# Setting dpi flag in image files generated using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

We're using ffmpeg to batch out some TIFF images that are being resized and having white borders created to fit specific paper sizes.

The resulting images default to 72dpi, even when the source is 300dpi. Is there a way to set the dpi flag in the output file?

Many thanks :-)

The command we're using:

```
for %%a in ("*.tif") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "scale=6974:4919:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=7016:4961:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white, format=rgb24" "%%~na A2 poster 594x420mm-Border.tif"
```

We have tried using -dpi 300 in the code but get the error that this is not a recognised.

Edit:

I have just managed to answer my own question:

```
for %%a in ("*.tif") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "scale=6974:4919:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=7016:4961:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white,format=rgb24" -dpi 300 "%%~na A2 poster 594x420mm-Border.tif"
```

I had been placing the -dpi 300 in the wrong place when I'd tried it...

Comment: Please share your whole command and the ffmpeg build that you are using! `ffmpeg -h full` tells `TIFF encoder AVOptions: -dpi <int>  set the image resolution (in dpi) (from 1 to 65536) (default 72)`.

Comment: Hi Markus, many thanks. I'd seen the -dpi <int>, so figured it ought to be possible. I have added the command to my original question now.

I'm running 2022-07-14-git-882aac99d2-full_build-www.gyan.dev